# Vanilla JS "elem.dataset.foo" vs. jQuery "$(elem).data('foo')"

Tags: javascript

I'm doing something wrong but can't figure out what.

Case:
I'm setting a data-attribute to an element when some data has loaded. I'm retrieving this value in Tag Manager (i.e. Vanilla JS).

When I retrieve the data in the console using jQuery, all is fine. Using Vanilla JS however, I end up with an empty DOMStringMap:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks for your help!

Comment: how did you populate the 'aid' data? where is that attribute on the element? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Comment: from jQuery: HTML5 data-* Attributes
Since jQuery 1.4.3, data-* attributes are used to initialize jQuery data. An element's data-* attributes are retrieved the first time the data() method is invoked upon it, and then are no longer accessed or mutated (all values are stored internally by jQuery).

Comment: @ThisGuy is correct: jQuery will **never** update the "data-foo" attributes via the `.data()` API.  If you're using jQuery, that is almost never a problem, because jQuery itself maintains the content without changing the DOM. By not touching the DOM at all, that (potentially) saves a bunch of work.

Comment: Great try, by the way.  using data-* attributes is fricking amazing, especially when using web components.